# How to fadeIn / fadeOut with timing issues with function using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this is a timing issue...

I have tab changes that reload a list of new items each time the tab changes (through the get_list function).

The 'get_list' function loads a list of items.  In the items, there are some with class='details'.  These details can be hidden or shown, depending on the checkbox if checked or not.  The list items load, but the details are not affected by the checkbox status.  I suspect because the timing of load occurs after the fadeIn/fadeOut are executed.

If so, how can this be made to work - is there a delay which can be incorporated before the fades get executed?  Or have code to check the list is loaded before executing the fades?

The console.log's verify correct changes and status of items.
When I manually click the checkbox, the fadeIn/fadeOut (in another scipt) works.

Code below:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   tab = e.target.id // newly activated tab
   get_list(my_feedback,user_id,status,tab,feedback_limit,feedback_start);
   console.log(tab);  
    if($('#hide_details').is(":checked")){//show various details
        console.log('is checked');
        $('.details').fadeIn();
        $('.link-no-blue').addClass('no-link').removeClass('link-no-blue');
    }else{//hide various details
        console.log('is NOT checked');
        $('.details').fadeOut();
        $('.no-link').addClass('link-no-blue').removeClass('no-link');
    }
});
```

Typical HTML:

```
<p class="details" style="margin:0px;"><strong>hotmail</strong><font color="#adb2ba">&nbsp;&nbsp;March 9, 2020&nbsp;&nbsp;User: 30</font>
    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#adb2ba">ID:124/features</font></span>
    <span style="float:right;"><span class="link edit_link" data-id="124">Edit</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><strong>Status: </strong>New</span>
    </span></p>
```

The get_list function:

```
function get_list( my_feedback,user_id,status,tab, feedback_limit, feedback_start ){
    $.ajax({
        url:"/modules/feedback/feedback_ajax_list.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{action:'get_list',
              my_feedback:my_feedback,
              user_id:user_id,
              status:status,
              tab:tab,
              feedback_limit:feedback_limit,
              feedback_start:feedback_start
            },
        success:function(data){
              //console.log(data);
              $("#data").append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: can you post a working code with html? or at your side try to do $('.details').fadeIn(1000); that will slow down the fadeIn

Comment: Adding 1000, or more to the fades did not  help.  Included more code to the question - typical html and the get_list function.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by placing the checkbox show/hide in the Ajax part of the get_list function.  Used show/hide instead since I am already fading in the list results:

```
function get_list( my_feedback,user_id,status,tab, feedback_limit, feedback_start ){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/modules/feedback/feedback_ajax_list.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:'get_list',
                  my_feedback:my_feedback,
                  user_id:user_id,
                  status:status,
                  tab:tab,
                  feedback_limit:feedback_limit,
                  feedback_start:feedback_start
                },
            success:function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                $("#data").append(data).hide().fadeIn(500);
                //show or hide details depending on the checkbox
                if($('#hide_details').is(":checked")){//show various details
                    console.log('is checked');
                    $('.details').show();
                    $('.link-no-blue').addClass('no-link').removeClass('link-no-blue');
                }else{//hide various details
                    console.log('is NOT checked');
                    $('.details').hide();
                    $('.no-link').addClass('link-no-blue').removeClass('no-link');
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Did not need to alter or add Async: false to ajax, seemed to have worked fine as is

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it and sure you need to show your controls when their data is ready and you need always to do that after call success;